# Parse Facebook login Again iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm using parse sdk with facebook to login/sign up the user. Everything is working fine. This is my code

```
- (void)_loginWithFacebook {
    // Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
      if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
      } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
      } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
      }
    }];
}
```

When i click on login button, it shows an alert with two options **Allow and No** . when allowed it signes me up but when i click no it says **User Cancelled the facebook login** .
Now what is actually i want to when user clicks NO and what to try again, it doesn't show the login alert box instead it says **User Cancelled the facebook login** again, How do i make it show the alert box again so the user can allow the app again to login.

Answer (score 0):

Once the permissions are not allowed, you need to go into the device's settings to allow the permission again. On a simulator, you can also `Reset Content and Settings` and this will reset this dialog, so you can keep testing either way and the dialog will keep reappearing.

Comment: but how does it work on other apps without doing any of those?

Comment: Most apps, once permissions have been denied, need to do something special to show them again. Is that your question? I guess I wasn't clear

Comment: no most apps, if the permissions is denied but they still decide to create an acc, they click on sign up with fb again and it asks for permissions again. But with this code, it doesn't asks for permission again instead it shows "user cancelled the facebook login"